# How to restrict a linux user to read only specific folder

Tags: linux, ssh, users, debian

I want to create a user that have only access to the following directories and can't see nothing else

```
/home/vehicles/ #read only
/home/images/  #read only
/home/dump/ #read and write
```

I used this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15360/how-to-add-a-ssh-user-who-only-has-permissions-to-access-specific-folder

so that I create a user group called testserver

```
 Match Group testserver
        ChrootDirectory %h
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and the chmod of those folders like the following

```
chmod -R 755 /home/vehicles/
chmod -R 755 /home/images/
chmod -R 765 /home/dump/
```

Everything went good except that testuser is still able to access other folders, how I prevent this user from accessing other folder(i.e only access those three folders)

Comment: `ChrootDirectory` only works if the target directory is owned by root -- and unless the home directory of `testuser` is `/home` itself that'll just lock them into their home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first off, change that directory structure to:

```
/home/testserver/vehicles
/home/testserver/images
/home/testserver/dump
```

Then execute

```
chown root.root /home/testserver /home/testserver/vehicles /home/testserver/images
chmod 755 /home/testserver
chown testuser.testserver /home/testserver/dump
chmod 775 /home/testserver/dump
```

Finally, alter the ChrootDirectory directive line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to

```
ChrootDirectory /home/testserver
```

I also recommend that you do a great deal of reading and brushing up on linux system administration in general, as your question and the things you attempted to do so far indicate "cargo cult" administration -- copy/pasting advanced administration tricks without understanding what they do or how they do it in the hope that they'll do what you want. This can *very* easily lead to disasters that you'll have no idea how to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer
But it still can access other files, I there exist a way to block this user from accessing anything else except /home/testserver/??

Comment: Is `/home/testserver/` owned by `root.root` ?

Comment: yes, but dump folder is owned by testuser

Comment: If you set up the `ChrootDirectory /home/testserver` directive and that directory is owned by root then the `internal-sftp` force command should keep it properly rooted in /home/testserver and only able to access `/dump/`, `/vehicles/` and `/images/`

Comment: yes when I logged in, it directs me to `/home/testuser` then I changed the directory to the parent folder `cd /home` and suddenly I am able to access any folder according to it's permission
for example those folders
`drwx---r-x 5 root     root      4096 Oct 25 08:00 `

`lib_dataDownloader drwx---r-x 2 root     root      4096 Oct 24 07:54 localX`

Comment: or folder like that /home/scripts
`drwxrwxrwx 3 root     root      4096 Oct 19 03:28 scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Remove testuser from the groups users and any other groups, as well as use grsecurity path to define your RBAC lists.

If you intend to login with testuser then it needs rights to /bin and others, like /proc.

Comment: Sorry could you please give me some extra details as I am new at Linux system

Comment: btw when I execute the following command 
`egrep -i "^testuser" /etc/passwd`
it's output 
`testuser:x:1002:1003:Test User,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash`